# Avoid using onClick to open a new window

Tags: javascript, onclick

I was wondering how I can avoid to use onClick here. I don't want to use it since when I do so, if I hit "Back" in my browser, it doesn't return me to the page where this code was but to two pages back and this is annoying!

Here is my code:

```
<table style="border :1px solid white;font-size:8pt;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial Narrow"
       width="240" height="30" CELLSPACING="0" >
    <tr onMouseOver="style.backgroundColor='#986828'"
        onMouseOut="style.backgroundColor=''"
        onClick="window.location.replace('presse.php')"style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: May I suggest that you move all styling out of your HTML and into a separate stylesheet. Makes your code much easier to read and debug!

Comment: Also, you can improve performance by using CSS `tr:hover {background-color: #986828;}` for your row mouseover, instead of javascript.

Comment: @James: That doesn't work in a browser that's still used by a substantial minority, especially companies.

Comment: The market share of IE6 isn't that substantial any more … and this is a cosmetic effect.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs about the code but my boss says she LOVES her website that she made and besides some minor chances to correct her mistakes, I can't edit a lot more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.replace` replaces the current page in the browser history.

Try this instead:

`onClick="location = 'presse.php';"`